# How can I push a CSS file to my main index page using Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I want to push some CSS file to my main page (Where all CSS and JS files are included).

I can push some JS file by using

`@stack('scripts')`

in the main page and in content page

`@push('scripts') // Scripts gone here // @endpush.`

So in a similar way how can I push some CSS files in laravel 5.4.

I tried with same way for CSS but no luck.

Any idea/suggestion is helpful.
Thanks

Comment: is your `@stack('css_files')` at the bottom of the page?

Comment: No I put css files at top. i.e inside head

Comment: i think this might be helpful https://laravel.io/forum/04-21-2017-laravel-not-rendering-stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't know the answer (did some googling, and it looks like you're not the only one with this problem), but I know an easy workaround:

**Main page**

```
@yield('css')
```

**Child pages**

```
@section('css')
    // CSS goes here
@stop
```

Comment: Yes. Now I feel I am a dumb because I push my page content into the main page in this way but never thought about this. Thanks

Comment: Looks like your username is perfect then, haha! Glad to help!

Comment: I wish I could put laugh emojis here.